# How to source CSS in Html5

Tags: css, html

I've to source a css file on my html5 file but out of the millions of ways I've seen on the internet none seem to work.
(Btw my css file is in the same folder as the html file.)

Comment: _Source_ it? Version it you mean?

Comment: Please show your HTML code.

Comment: What is source? Comment? Adding in your html?

Answer (score 1):

To load a css ressource in an HTML5 document, use the [link element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) inside the [head element](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTML/Element/head).

In the following example, the ressource `style.css` is located in the same folder than the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```